# Forms Authentication, .Net 3.5 + IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-6

I changed the Intranet site's authentication method from Windows to Forms, using AD authentication. It works when I launch it from VS 2008, goes directly yo login.aspx page and after loggin in goes to default.aspx.
When I use the URL it tries to go to default.aspx directly and says you are not authorized to view this page, instead of going to login.aspx page. Not sure what I am missing here. In IIS, I enabled anonymous access and checked everything else off. In web.config I have the following:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="5" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

<membership defaultProvider="CMSOracleMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="CMSOracleMembershipProvider"
          type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"
          connectionStringName="CMSConnectionString"
          applicationName="/"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="4"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="9"
          passwordAttemptWindow="8"/>
    </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CMSOracleRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="CMSOracleRoleProvider"
           type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleRoleProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"
        connectionStringName="CMSConnectionString"
        applicationName="/"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I don't have an asp login control, but a couple of textboxes for id and password and I handle the authentication using AD.

I appreciaet your help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340

Second, it sounds like maybe the directory holding your login.aspx page may *not* be configured to allow anonymous access.  You will need to drop a web.config file in that directory that is set to allow everyone.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have a web.config in that folder with allow="*" in it. To be on the safe side, I added a <loaction> in the root web.config as well to allow access to that folder for all. The link is actually exactly the one I followed to implement AD authentication with forms.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was: the anonymous user I was using, who was supposed to be a user with access to AD, had his ID entered incorrectly; I was missing the domain name in front of the user ID. However, I now have another problem: I boomark a page; close the browser, open a new browser and select the bookmarked page; it correctly goes to login page with return url set correctly; but when I enter user id and passowrd, it clears them, gets rid of the return url in the address bar and sits at login.aspx and expects user id and password. After I supply them again, goes to default.aspx.

Comment: @NoBullMan: You might want to open a new question about that.  Sounds like a config issue with the login control.